# web3.eth.contracts.method await function never returns

Tags: javascript, async-await, ethereum, web3js

I'm working on a project to interact with a smart contract in ethereum. Everything was working fine, the transactions was working properly and so on... but I realized that when I tried to run some code after an specifically await function, that code never ran and I really don't know why. Others contract methods that I invoked is working well and the code is executed normally.

The code:

```
onSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitting the form...")
  var day = new Date(Date.now()).getDate()
  var month = new Date(Date.now()).getMonth() + 1
  var year = new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear()
  var today = new Date(year, month -1, 1)
  var todayTime = today.getTime()

  const ipfsadded = await ipfs.add({path:this.state.fileName, content:this.state.buffer})
  var ipfsHash = ipfsadded.cid.toString()
  this.setState({ipfsHash: ipfsHash})
  console.log('hash:', ipfsHash, " / name =", this.state.fileName )

  console.log("inserindo na blockchain..")

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  //ERROR HERE!!
  //THIS FUNCTION IS EXECUTED, THE TRANSACTION IS CONFIRMED IN METAMASK BUT AFTER THAT NOTHING HAPPENS
  var result = await contract.methods.add(ipfsHash, this.state.fileName, this.state.fileType, todayTime).send({from:accounts[0], gas:300000});
  console.log("resultado =", result) //IS NEVER EXECUTED EVEN WITH TRANSACTION OK
  console.log("File submitted on blockchain!") //IS NEVER EXECUTED


}
```

Comment: Could you try wrappin the line with a try/catch block, so you can print out an error easily?
I suspect that this error because it took more than 750 seconds to be mined and threw out an error. You can read about the 750 seconds at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#transactionpollingtimeout.

Comment: If that's the case then it's better to follow this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/58936/6814, by subscribing on either `receipt` or `confirmation` event instead of waiting for the promise to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that is because the transaction wasn't mined within 750 seconds and `.send` threw an error, but wasn't caught. You can prove this by by wrapping it with a try/catch block and inspect the error.

```js
  try {
    var result = await contract.methods.add(ipfsHash, this.state.fileName, this.state.fileType, todayTime).send({from:accounts[0], gas:300000});
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

A better way is to subscribe to either `receipt`, `transactionHash` or `confirmation` event, which is exposed by `send`.

```js
  contract.methods.add(ipfsHash, this.state.fileName, this.state.fileType, todayTime)
    .send({from:accounts[0], gas:300000})
    .on('transactionHash', resolve)
    .on('error', reject);
```

In your case it would be

```js
onSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log("Submitting the form...")
  var day = new Date(Date.now()).getDate()
  var month = new Date(Date.now()).getMonth() + 1
  var year = new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear()
  var today = new Date(year, month -1, 1)
  var todayTime = today.getTime()

  const ipfsadded = await ipfs.add({path:this.state.fileName, content:this.state.buffer})
  var ipfsHash = ipfsadded.cid.toString()
  this.setState({ipfsHash: ipfsHash})
  console.log('hash:', ipfsHash, " / name =", this.state.fileName )

  console.log("inserindo na blockchain..")

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  //ERROR HERE!!
  //THIS FUNCTION IS EXECUTED, THE TRANSACTION IS CONFIRMED IN METAMASK BUT AFTER THAT NOTHING HAPPENS
  const promise = new Promise()
  contract.methods.add(ipfsHash, this.state.fileName, this.state.fileType, todayTime)
  .send({from:accounts[0], gas:300000})
  .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.log('this should be executed now')
    console.log("resultado =", receipt)
    console.log("File submitted on blockchain!")
  })
  .on('error', console.error)
}
```

Either of these answers https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/58936/6814 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/59114/6814 are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

With the inclusion of the try/catch block in just once the 750 second timeout error was shown. The rest of the time, there was no error.

And including those events, just the transactionHash was executed. And just to be clear, the transaction it is mined and confirmed. Here is an example of a transaction that I sent: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x431932ddbe1d649a542781656ab4e0ee60effd690cba5f100415427e1de2d601

Comment: @GabrielMS Sorry, the code example in my answer was incorrect.
You shouldn't `await` on `send()`, but have the promise resolved within `.on('transactionHash', resolve)` instead.

Comment: @GabrielMS I've added your code that's corrected. It should work now.